# Invalid column name when selecting

Tags: sql

I have a table called `Jobs` with the following column names: `JobID`, `Name`, and `Value`. The table is filled like just one entry: `JobID`: 1, `Name`: TestJob, `Value`: 10

I want to do `select * from Jobs where Name="TestJob"`, but this gives me an error saying "Invalid column name 'TestJob'". Why can't I select by the value of the `Name` column? Doing `JobID=1` or `Value=10` will give me the proper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.  Single quotes are the standard for SQL string and date constants:

```
select *
from Job
where Name = 'TestJob';
```

Some databases do accept double quotes for this purpose.  It is always safest to use single quotes for string and date constants and double quotes to escape identifier names (if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Change your double quotes `"` to single quotes `'`.  Double quotes are used to surround object names, probably in the same way `[]` can be used, so you can have spaces and other normally-invalid object name characters in the object name.  Single quotes, on the other hand, are used for string literals.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **'** instead of **"**. It will work.